# Random WiFi Disconnection with Empty Connection List with KDE Plasma

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, kde, 17.04

My current desktop environment is KDE Plasma 5.9.4 on Ubuntu 17.04 and, on random occasions when I am connected to a wireless network, it would disconnect and would not be able to reconnect or even allow me connect to another wireless network because not networks would be shown in the network list.

Everything this this occurs, I would have to restart the network manager service using the command `sudo service network-manager restart` which has become quite annoying.

I have tried other Desktop Environments including GNOME in which everything works as expected but I would like to keep KDE Plasma as my default.

Comment: what wifi card do you have?

Comment: Intel PROSet Wirelesss

Comment: it could be a driver issue ... I'm not sure about that card

Comment: The thing is I tried another Desktop Environment (GNOME) I the problem no longer exists but I would prefer to stick with KDE.

Comment: that is odd, sorry I can't help further